# Where to make api call everytime a modal opens in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a modal which should be opened on a button click. 
Based on button click, it triggers an open action with an id, this id is added to the state.

But issue is I am not able to access this id from state before the render of modal (while modal opens).

Flow of events are like this:

Button click --> dispatch openmodal action with id --> active prop turns true --> modal opens.

But before modal render im not able to access the id.

Comment: can you create and share a sandbox of your code

Comment: @reactdoubt post your code what you have tried?

Comment: openmodal dispatch can handle the api request with the help of a middleware, when your modal opens it would show spinner until your original component brings the response from api request. since it's modal, your original component will never unmount so you can handle it there. don't forget to call componentWillUnmount while closing the modal though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or a similar library for this. Within a redux-thunk action you have access to the current state and you can also dispatch actions.

```js
const myAction = () => (dispatch, getState) => {

  // get state here and dispatch actions with it
  const id = getState().modalId;

  dispatch({
    type: 'ANOTHER_ACTION',
    modalId
  });
}
```